# How to return with POST after PayPal billing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I created the next form:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="team@team.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Subscription">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.my_website.com/<%= params[:locale] %>/success">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">
  <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

But it redirects to my website via GET request. How can I redirect to my website via POST request after payment?

When I create my button in PayPal button factory:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SOME_VALUE">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/IL/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

When I click on the PayPal button, I have set up success and cancel redirects when I click on the PayPal button, but the following error is displayed:

```
PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem.
```

So, how can I change my first code that it will perform a POST redirect after billing?

Comment: Why do you want to redirect to post? Instead of that on redirected page you can write hidden form and auto submit it through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/"

and "rm" variable for solutions. And also set the hidden fields values for the paypal payment submissions.